# Meaning of this SELECT statement, which does a comparison of two string values

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I am reading **MySQL in 10 Minutes**.

On page 63, there is an example that isn't explained very well.

```
SELECT 'abc' = 'ABC';
```

This gives the following result:

```
+----------------+
| 'abc' = 'ABC'  |
+----------------+
|              1 |
+----------------+
```

What is the meaning of the table entry "1"? Does it mean that the value of the expression 'abc'='ABC' is 1? Or does it mean that there is one row for which the expression is true?

I did a quick Google search, which says that SQL is supposed to have a Boolean type that gives the value of conditional expressions. Is that correct? If that is true, why is the value of the table 1 and not a Boolean?

Comment: Doesn't MySQL have 1 as boolean true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1 is a representation of a Boolean (True) just the same. In the case of MySQL, actually 1 is literally how it represents True, as it [doesn't have a native Boolean type](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-boolean/).

You are correct in your assumption, the query is evaluating abc = ABC and the result is True, therefore that 1 you are seeing is just the evaluated value.

Answer (score 3):

MySQL supports boolean values as integers.  The value of a boolean expression is `1` for true and `0` for false.  So, the `1` means "true".  Most other databases would either return an error (because they don't support boolean types) or give the value as `true`.

With boolean operators, the rules are that `0` is false and anything other than `0` (and `NULL`) is treated as true.